# Freemarker print 0.00 values in print (library:opemhtmltopdf)

Tags: java, freemarker

He all I'm trying to print some values in print with 2 decimal places. If value is string ("1200.00") then it printing fine.
But value is Double 100.00. it's printing 100 without any decimal. But I want to print with .00

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as 100 versus 100.00 with the `Double` type. That's just a formatting difference, which is not stored inside the `Double` itself. Try `${someValue?string('0.00')}`, which will format all numbers with exactly 2 decimals. (You can also change the default number format in FreeMarker, or define named formatting styles.)